# Android Estabilish Connection error for seng Json Request

Tags: android, json, android-json

i simple code to send requset data to server using Json Object with sample on web. after loading requet URL i get successfull result . but i can not send any request from andrid application and i get this error:`Cannot Estabilish Connection`

My result on web :

```
["Hello"]
```

My simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sendJson("tsms_mahdi","123456");
    }

    protected void sendJson(final String username, final String password) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("site.com/example.php");  /* -> http://www.example.com/example.php*/
                    json.put("username", username);
                    json.put("password", password);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){
                        //Get the data in the entity
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        Log.e("Content", "in");
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };

        t.start();
    }
}
```

whats my code problem? i get error in this line :

```
response = client.execute(post);
```

UPDATE :

```
Error﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=example.com/example.php
```

Comment: write down what the error says

Comment: in this line `HttpPost post = new HttpPost("site.net/example.php");` make sure the site is written in full form starting from http

Comment: @Elgert i'm wrote full url in application but i get error that

Answer (score 0):

Try my code and substitute your values

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String message;
            HttpPost p = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/example.php");
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {

                object.put("username", username);
                object.put("password", password);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                message = object.toString();
                p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
                p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(p);
                if (resp != null) {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                    if (responseBody.length() > 0) {
                             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and jsonResponse is the response from the webservice